# swagger for spring: No mapping found

Tags: java, spring, swagger-2.0, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to make a documentation of my API with swagger.

My REST API is written with the help of spring and typical Controller looks like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mymapping")
public class ParameterController {

@Autowired
Mydao myDao;

    /**
     * GET list
     * 
     * @return The resulting string
     */
    //produces replaced accept-header
    @RequestMapping(value="/Parameter", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, "application/ld+json"})
    public @ResponseBody List<String> getAllParameters() {

    List<String> params= myDao.getAllParameters();
    return params;
    }

}
```

To configurate the Swagger I followed the instruction [here](http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api):

1. added a package in Maven
2. created a configuration Java class `SwaggerConfig` (I use only Java-configuration for Spring)
3. added resource Handlers to the existing class extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`
4. added packages "io.swagger" and "springfox.documentation" to the `@ComponentScan` annotation of the same class extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

But each time when I call http://localhost:8080/spring-security-rest/api/v2/api-docs I receive

```
16:43:43,370  WARN qtp1072754634-13 servlet.PageNotFound:1136 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring-security-rest/api/v2/api-docs] in DispatcherServlet with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-437a7f13'
```

The system searches the path `/spring-security-rest/api/v2/api-docs` among the controllers' mappings. And does not find it.

What did I forget?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved mine by placing the SwaggerConfig Java Class in the same package where I had a the class with @SpringBootApplication.

Heres a suggestion:

Typically this is due to improper use of component scan. You can read more about component scan here (read the 2 questions fully :) )

Click here for the [2 questions](https://github.com/in28minutes/in28minutes-initiatives/tree/master/The-in28Minutes-TroubleshootingGuide-And-FAQ#q---what-is-the-need-for-a-component-scan)

Answer (score 0):

my `SwaggerConfig` class look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket beerMapApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                    .paths(regex("/api.*"))
                    .build()
                .pathMapping("/")
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    @Bean
    public UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
        return UiConfiguration.DEFAULT;
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("title")
                .description("description")
                .version("0.1")
                .build();
    }

}
```

and this is how my `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.addResourceHandlers` looks:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "com.something.server.controller" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

Comment: is this WebMvcConfigurerAdapter configurated especially for Swagger or it works also for the controllers?

Comment: now my classes look like yours. But it still looks for the  /spring-security-rest/api/v2/api-docs among the controllers' mappings

Comment: are you scanning SwaggerConfig?

Comment: yes, the path to SwaggerConfig is added to @ComponentScan

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any solution to this?

Comment: try to remove @EnableWebMvc and check it again.